# System.Reflection.Emit - How to add attribute to return type definition?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I'm defining some types via System.Reflection.Emit. Imagine that I want to have method signature with some custom attributes, something like this:

```
[return: MyAttr]
MyType MethodName([MyOtherAttr] MyOtherType);
```

I use such code to generate it:

```
TypeBuilder t = assembly.DefineType(...);

MethodAttributes methodAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.NewSlot;
MethodBuilder method = t.DefineMethod("MethodName", methodAttr, typeof(MyType), new Type[] { typeof(MyOtherType) });
method.SetImplementationFlags(MethodImplAttributes.Runtime | MethodImplAttributes.Managed);

// return type
ParameterBuilder pbr = method.DefineParameter(0, ParameterAttributes.Retval, null);
CustomAttributeBuilder cabr = GetMyAttrBuilder();
pbr.SetCustomAttribute(cabr);

// parameter
ParameterBuilder pbp = method.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, null);
CustomAttributeBuilder cabp = GetMyOtherAttrBuilder();
pbp.SetCustomAttribute(cabp);

t.CreateType();
```

But the generated method signature is:

```
MyType MethodName([MyOtherAttr] MyOtherType);
```

The return attribute is missing :( Any idea how to achieve right behavior?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in question is working well just the C# disassembler does not shows it, il one does.